# Android - How to set key icon from code

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

When defining keyboard in xml , we use **android:keyIcon** attribute to set the key icon.
But when setting the *Drawable* property - *Key.icon*, the icon is not getting displayed *on* the key. Instead, the image is getting displayed in the popup that appears when tapping the key.Is there any other way to set key icon from code?